# How do I access subviews during a segue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm trying to make a simple segue in which subviews of both the source and destination views are animated.

I'm having trouble accessing subviews on my source view in my segue class in order to animate them. What is the easiest way to access and animate subviews of the source view during a segue?

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
// Source view controller
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    // other normal view controller code
}

class mySegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            // how do I access and animate myButton?
            // source.myButton
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
class MySegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            let sourceController = self.source as! ViewController
            sourceController.myButton
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, can you help me understand why it works?

Comment: Ok, after many hours grappling with this, I've realized why it works. `self.source` refers to the UIViewController superclass of your view controller. You must cast it as your subclass. In this case, that subclass is named `ViewController` which is the default name apple gives you. That subclass will have your custom properties. If you have a different view controller subclass, make sure you use *it's* name.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: If you want to animate something as you transition away from a scene, you can animate alongside the transition:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
        self.myButton.backgroundColor = .red            // animate change of background color during transition
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

---

Also, another alternative to subclassing segue, you can do custom transitions. See WWDC 2013 [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/). It depends upon the nature of the transition and associated animations. But this is a great way to do really robust and rich transitions.

Comment: Thanks, from what I've gathered, using custom segues (as I am doing) isn't the correct way to do this, and I will look into alternatives like those you suggested. I've accepted the other answer since it directly addresses the technique I used.